# How to login within reddit using Selenium and Python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait, reddit

I'm trying to automatize the reddit logIn with selenium from python and i'm using the following code in order to do it

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from time import sleep

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.reddit.com/")

login=driver.find_element_by_link_text("Log In")
login.click()

username = "the-username"          # Enter your username
password = "the-password"                   # Enter your password

def slow_typing(element, text): 
   for character in text: 
      element.send_keys(character)
      sleep(0.3)

def logIn():            # Log In Function.
    try: 
        sleep(15)
        #username_in = driver.find_element_by_class_name("AnimatedForm__textInput")
        username_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loginUsername']")
        slow_typing(username_in, username)

        pass_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loginPassword']")
        slow_typing(pass_in,password)

        pass_in.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        sleep(5)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Llegue aqui xd xd")

logIn()
```

There's a little more code, but I'm posting a summary so I can tell my problem to you guys. When it is running, it comes to the moment where the input of the username is selected, but it doesn't send the keys. I don't know what to do or change, so I ask for some help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def logIn():            # Log In Function.
    try:
        driver.switch_to_frame(driver.find_element_by_tag_name('iframe'))
        sleep(5)
        print("hii")
        #username_in = driver.find_element_by_class_name("AnimatedForm__textInput")
        username_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loginUsername']")
        slow_typing(username_in, username)

        pass_in = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='loginPassword']")
        slow_typing(pass_in, password)

        pass_in.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        sleep(5)
        driver.switch_to_default_content()
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print("Llegue aqui xd xd")
        driver.switch_to_default_content()
```

The login is inside an iframe witch to it first

Answer (score 1):

To login within [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/) using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) and [python](/questions/tagged/python) you need to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52603847/how-to-sleep-webdriver-in-python-for-milliseconds/52607451#52607451) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
    options.add_argument("start-maximized")
    options.add_experimental_option("prefs", { \
        "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1 
      })
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
    driver.get("https://www.reddit.com/")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@href, 'https://www.reddit.com/login')]"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.XPATH,"//iframe[starts-with(@src, 'https://www.reddit.com/login')]")))
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@id='loginUsername']"))).send_keys("debanjanb")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@id='loginPassword']").send_keys("zergcore")
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='AnimatedForm__submitButton m-full-width']").click()
    ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
   from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
   from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: reddit_login]

Comment: It worked as well. The secret is changing to the iframe

Answer (score 0):

That happens because you don't click inside the input element - below you'll find a small change in your slow typing method, also if have a close look at their code they also have an animation for those fields, clicking the input should solve your issue.

```
    def slow_typing(element, text):
       element.click()
       for character in text: 
          element.send_keys(character)
          sleep(0.3)
```

The second recommendation is to use ids instead of XPath whenever you have the chance. Ids give you the best performance and also helps the framework to find the elements easily and not to parse the entire DOM to match the xpath.

Comment: It went to the same place it did before, just to select the element, still not sending the keys.